# Can you create Jira release notes from Cruise control or Nant?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, jira

I would like to include release notes with every release of our intranet project. We use Jira. Is there a way to generate the release notes automatically based on the fixes that were submitted to SVN? We usually check the files back with the jira key id.

Answer (score 1):

vikasde,

To my knowledge Jira does not offer a way to retrieve this information in a straight-forward manner on a jira number basis.  However, it has been quite some time since I looked into this.  Jira does generate release notes for all jiras contained within a release (fixes checked in or not).  What I have done in the past, as part of the release build, is to have a script retrieve the contents of the "Edit/Copy Release Notes" jira url and paste that into an xml file stored within the build products.  If there is a better way to achieve this functionality I would definitely be interested as well.

EDIT: It appears that starting in Jira 3.5 you can retrieve issues by id through the soap interface.

Comment: can you post the url to the soap interface? I cant seem to find it.